# AgGrid: fixed header with pinned bottom rows

Tags: ag-grid

I'm using **ag-grid-community v.25.1.0** with 2-rows header and 5 pinned bottom rows.
I want the grid header to be **always at fixed position** - even when I scroll to the last data rows of my grid (which are often far below the screen bottom).

Unfortunately this forces me to set 'height = 100vh' for the grid - but then the 5 pinned bottom rows also occupy screen area, so there's too small height left for the data rows (about 10 data rows left when I'm using my 13-inch laptop). See demo #1 at https://codesandbox.io/s/aggrid-issue-demo-j9ls9

And if I do not limit grid height with 100vh - then the pinned bottom rows go ouside the screen together with the data rows (because AgGrid's OWN vertical scrollbar is no more shown) which is OK except for... scrolling down the vertical scrollbar of the grid's container (body tag) *moves grid's header outside the screen* (although "I want header to be always at fixed position" - see this requirement above!). See demo #2 at https://codesandbox.io/s/aggrid-issue-demo-2-52bo3 - it would be OK if header stayed at *fixed* position.

If there were no pinned bottom rows - the problem would not exist. But these pinned rows are really necessary in my app; however the fact that they occupy ~33% of the grid's height - is a real problem. Yes, I can make row height smaller (together with the font used to paint the cells) - but that's an *ugly workaround*, not a *real solution*. I can also provide users with a possibility to show/hide some of the pinned bottom rows (using several checkboxes) - but this "solution" also smells (besides, in most cases all 5 pinned rows are needed).

Is there any solution? maybe I can adjust header's CSS so that it's Y-coordinate stays strictly fixed? in such case removing 'height = 100vh' would solve my problem...

**UPD:** maybe it makes sense to describe the difference between demos #1 and #2:

**App.css:**

- added this file to override the ".ag-root-wrapper-body.ag-layout-normal" style - because it had height set to zero

**App.tsx:**

- added import for App.css (see above)
- removed div style "height: '100vh'"

**index.html:**

- removed body style "overflow-y: hidden;" (to enable vertical scrollbar which is needed to access last rows after we removed '100vh' above)

Comment: Nope, demo #2 is a no-go: in this case to access grid's horizontal scrollbar I'll need to scroll down to the very bottom. In other words, to always see grid's horizontal scrollbar I have to limit grid height (e.g. set it to 100vh as in demo #1).
Seems the only solution would be to have grid's own vertical scrollbar to scroll both data rows and pinned bottom rows - but that's impossible. And it's logical: the latter are PINNED rows :) In fact I'm missing kind of "footer" rows - which are **not** pinned but are always placed under the data rows and do not participate in filtering and sorting!

Comment: Well, it seems that I need to migrate from Ag-Grid to Ant Design Table, because the latter has the following feature: "Fixed header and scroll bar with the page: For long table, need to scroll to view the header and scroll bar, then you can now set the fixed header and scroll bar to follow the page". Watched the demo (https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-sticky) - seems that's exactly what I need. And they have "Summary" instead of "pinned rows" - that's also fine.